# How do I get the ID of the UpdatePanel(s) in ASP.NET AJAX that a response is destined for?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I'm trying to run some jQuery initialization code when new elements appear in the DOM as a result of an async request in an UpdatePanel.  I can't seem to find the piece of data I want in the arguments to the endRequestHandler.

Anyone know where the data I'm looking for is located?

```
            function onEndRequest(sender, e) {
                // run some jQuery initialization code (e.g. .tabs()) 
               // here. but only on the affected updatepanel(s)
            }

            with (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()) {
                add_endRequest(onEndRequest);
            }
```

Alternatively, I could run my initialization code over the HTML in the response (if that's even possible).  Any ideas?

Comment: Just a quick one, with a bit of necromancy and off-topicness: using "with" in javascript is not recommended, for code clarity and safety. It's also removed from ES5 strict mode. http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `args.get_panelsUpdating();` within the pageLoaded handler to get a collection of update panels who's content has been refreshed.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequest);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
   var updatedPanels = args.get_panelsUpdated();
   for (i=0; i < updatedPanels.length; i++) {            
       $(updatedPanels[i]).children('.tabContainer').tabs();
   }
}
```

**References:**

- [Ajax Page Life Cycle Event Handler
     Arguments](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AjaxClientPageLifeCycle2.aspx?display=Print)
- [MSDN -
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager
  pageLoaded Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.aspx)